# How to add multiple subtitle in fluent FFMPEG nodejs

Tags: ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I searched and found some commands that using FFmpeg commands, but I cannot convert to work in the fluent FFmpeg, so requesting to help me.

This is the command I found on another answer

```
ffmpeg -i $movie.mov -i $sub_en.srt -i $sub_de.srt \
-map 0:v -map 0:a -map 1 -map 2 \
-c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s srt \
-metadata:s:s:0 language=eng -metadata:s:s:1 language=ger \
$output.mkv
```

This is how I added subtitle stream on fluent FFmpeg.

```
ffmpeg()
    .addInput("./sample3.mp4")
    .addInput("merged.wav")
    .outputOptions(
      "-vf subtitles=./subt/114.srt:force_style='Alignment=10,FontName=QCF2604,Fontsize=18,MarginL=5,MarginV=25,Outline=0'"
    )
    .outputOptions(
      "-vf subtitles=dd.srt:force_style='Alignment=1,FontName=QCF2604,Fontsize=18,MarginL=5,MarginV=25,Outline=0'"
    )
    .outputOptions("-shortest")

    .output("./test.mp4")
    .on("end", function () {
      console.log("conversion ended");
      callback(null);
    })
    .on("error", function (e) {
      console.log("error: ", e.code, e.msg, e);
      callback(e);
    })
    .run();
}
```

But by this way, only the second subtitle is appearing on the video. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a way!

```
ffmpeg()
    .addInput("./sample3.mp4")
    .addInput("./ayahs/114.png")
    .addInput("merged.wav")

    .addInput("color=black:s=600x1000:r=25") // Background Overlay
    .inputFormat("lavfi")

    .complexFilter([
      subtitles=./subt/114.srt:force_style='Alignment=10,FontName=QCF2604,Fontsize=14,MarginL=5,MarginV=25,Outline=0'[subt1]", // arabic subtitle
      "[subt1]subtitles=./subt/114_trans.srt:force_style='Alignment=2,FontName=FML-Leela,Fontsize=8,MarginL=15,MarginV=115,Outline=0'", // malayalam subtitle
    ])

    .outputOptions("-shortest")
    .output("./test.mp4")
    .on("end", function () {
      console.log("conversion ended");
      callback(null);
    })
    .on("error", function (e) {
      console.log("error: ", e.code, e.msg, e);
      callback(e);
    })
    .run();
}
```